# What is the role of provisioningstate property of a resource group

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-management, azure-resource-group

Using powershell I ran the following command 
**Get-AzureRmResourceGroup**
and got some information on my resource group. One of the properties mentioned is Provisioningstate which in my case is Succeeded and I assume could be Failed as well.

1- When and how is this property set for a resource group?

2 -Where can I see this in Azure Web portal? Is this the same as *Last-deployment property* on the web portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When and how is this property set for a resource group?

This property is set automatically by `Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API` whenever you perform some operation on the resource group itself. So for example, when you delete a resource group, while it is deleting the resource group and the resources inside it, the status changes to `Deleting`.

> Where can I see this in Azure Web portal? Is this the same as
>   Last-deployment property on the web portal?

By default, this is not visible on Azure Portal. To see the status, when viewing resource groups, first click on `Columns` button and then select `Status` column and then you should be able to see the resource group status.

[image]